# Add string at the beginning of each line with the name of the file

Tags: linux, shell, freebsd

I cannot find an easy solution for this problem in bash.

I have several files: **aaa.txt**  /  **bbb.txt**   /  **ccc.txt**

The content of each file is:

aaa.txt

```
    1234
    1234
    1234
```

bbb.txt

```
    5678
    5678
    5678
```

ccc.txt

```
    10
    20
    30
    40
```

I need to add the name of the file to the beginning of each line using a loop.

There are about 300 files and I want to concatenate all of them in one file to do a grep instead of looking file by file, and the reason to add the name of the file is to do that grep. This should be the result:

aaa.txt

```
    aaa: 1234
    aaa: 1234
    aaa: 1234
```

bbb.txt

```
    bbb: 5678
    bbb: 5678
    bbb: 5678
```

ccc.txt

```
    ccc: 10
    ccc: 20
    ccc: 30
    ccc: 40
```

Could you help me?

If there is any doubt just ask for it

Thanks!

Comment: ```grep -e ".*" * > result``` and grep will add the file name at the beginning of the line. But then you can grep immediately too, probably

Comment: You could use `grep -H` to force grep results with the filename. You don't discuss *how* you are currently using grep, but I think this may help: if you're doing something like `for file in *; do grep "$pattern" "$file"; done > result`, then throw `-H` in there to get the filename in the result file.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `-H` option, which prefixes the file name for every line searched.  `^` matches the beginning of every line:

```
grep -H ^ *.txt > bigfile.txt
```

---

Note that doing this:

```
grep -H ^ *.txt > bigfile.txt
grep searchstring bigfile.txt
```

...can be simplified to this:

```
grep -H searchstring *.txt
```

...which is also about twice as efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, what agc said is the one that worked:

cd /some/path/ && grep -H ^ *.txt > /some/path/bigfile.txt

Thanks everyone!